# youtube-dl latin-1 codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

Youtube-dl error latin-1' codec can't encode characters

I am trying to download a course video offline but facing this error i am using

```
youtube-dl -v (url) --add-header cookie:"(cookie content)"
```

Facing error :
latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 512: ordinal not in range (256)

Comment: It appears that the cookie content contains the character `…` which is not in the latin-1 character set. See if the`--encoding` parameter will help.

Comment: hi,i tried --encoding utf-8 but no use

Comment: If you don't provide a stack trace, we don't know which piece of code inside youtube-dl failed. Note that questions about **using** software someone else wrote are off-topic here; to be on-topic, it needs to be a question about _writing_ software.

Comment: `--no-restrict-filenames` could help too

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--restrict-filenames` option:

```
youtube-dl --restrict-filenames <youtube.url>
```